# How to make an object transparent in the viewport?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, 3d-view, shaders

[image]

I would like to make one of my objects transparent in the 3D Viewport. When I look around I get tons of answers - all different, and some of them a lot more complicated than others and also older from versions of Blender. I can't get any of them to work. I just want the simplest way to make anything transparent; like descreasing the alpha channel or checking an x-ray parameter or something like that. Any ideas?

I tried `bpy.context.active_object.show_transparent=True` but I'm sure what it does, but it seems like what I want.

Here are some of the links I found:

- [Blender view-port transparent objects How to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbz0Pfe8qVU) This illustrates the effect I would like and it is only a few simple commands, but I can't find the functionality he describes.
- [Show transparent viewport image (via script)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143633/show-transparent-viewport-image-via-script) - Very complicated and incomplete
- https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/scene-view-alpha-transparency.php - Very long and comprehensive.
- [Material Opacity in viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/material-opacity-in-viewport) - Just what I want, but I can't find the functions.
- I also think I read something about an x-ray setting. But this might have been an addon. But that would be fine for my purpose.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add some reference images of what you call "transparent" and the links to the answers that weren't helpful...

Comment: You are talking about the solid view, not material preview or rendering, right ?

Comment: Better! Related: [Code to toggle viewport display material alpha](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199455/code-to-toggle-viewport-display-material-alpha/199469#199469) I'd recommend do what ever you want to to in the GUI first, then find a way doing it with python.

Comment: but you also have to set viewport shading to "object" (@brockmann)

Comment: Eurika! I have an image so that I can answer my own question.

Comment: You mean "solid" shading @lemon ?

Comment: @brockmann, yes solid then in viewport shading, select "object" (if object color has transparency in its viewport display)

Comment: @brockmann I'm talking about solid view. I think your link is the same as what I stumble upon. Also it's a good tip to try the GUI first and see the python command below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to set the alpha value (fourth component) of [`Material.diffuse_color`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse_color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color):

> float array of 4 items in [0, inf], default (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)

```
import bpy

# Get the object in context
obj = bpy.context.object

# Get the active material
mat = obj.active_material

# Set the alpha value of the diffuse color
mat.diffuse_color = (0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.7)
```

[image]